# Plot a Map of a Neural Network in Keras

Tags: keras, neural-network, visualization

is there a way to plot a map of a Keras-Model like in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0bs7.png)
 (form R-Package "neuralnet")?

I think this kind of a map is very useful to learn what is going on behind the scenes.

Scrabyard

Comment: You can use this library: https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron. This supports variety of file type (including Keras's .h5 and .keras)